# 1130 Host 'amazon-ec2-ip' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, remote-access

I am facing a problem in accessing the mysql DB on one of my Amazon EC2 servers from another EC2 server. I read through various articles regarding providing appropriate permissions for mysql to be accessed from external IP addresses, and here are the steps that I followed:

1. Opened port 3306 on my host EC2 instance to allow for external Mysql connection.
2. In the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf, changed the "bind-address" from "127.0.0.1" to "0.0.0.0".
3. Opened mysql using root, and executed the following command:
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to worker@'ec2-ip-address' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

As per all the blogs/articles that I read, this should have solved the issue, but i keep getting the following error:

```
1130  Host 'amazon-ec2-ip' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

The ip address I was providing for the EC2 instance was an elastic IP that gets generated when you create an instance. To verify whether the issue is specific to EC2, I tried executing the command "3" for a different "static ip address". Now, this worked for me (i.e. I was able to login to the mysql host from that remote server), so it is sure that the above steps are correct.

Why is the Amazon EC2 ip address not working?

Comment: Silly question, but are the `ec2-ip-address` to which you granted privileges and the `amazon-ec2-ip` in the error one and the same?

Comment: @eggyal: ya ya.....they are the same....my bad here !

Comment: Just to add one more comment for clarification -- the "static ip" address....that I mentioned here was not an EC2 machine. It was another linode instance. I even tried to connect from another EC2 instance, which had a "static ip address", but that too didn't work !!

Comment: Looks like EC2 does not translate a connection from an external internet IP to the public IP or instance address of the EC2 instance. It means the connecting client IP will be presented to MySQL and not the "ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.DATACENTER.compute.amazonaws.com"

In the "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on dbname.% to username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';" 

..the % sign in username@'%' will permit ALL networks from where connection is made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After posting this problem, as I was working, I realized that I wasn't even able to ping to the EC2 server or telnet to it. So something basic had to be wrong. Finally a friend helped me out with the problem. As I had expected, the problem was very specific to EC2.

The details are as follows:

When we create an EC2 instance, we get an external IP address which is similar to: ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

While setting the permissions in the mysql I was granting the permissions to the above IP address, i.e.:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on . to worker@'ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.ap-southeast1.compute.amazonaws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This does not work when you try to communicate to an EC2 instance from another local EC2 instance. For this, you need to provide the 'internal ip address" of the EC2 instance, which can be found using the ip command:

ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 12:31:41:02:58:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet **XX.XX.XX.XXX/23** brd YY.YYY.YY.YYY scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::1031:41ff:fe02:5847/64 scope link 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

To get things working correctly, you need to grant the permission to the ip address --"XX.XXX.XX.XXX/23", and it should work. Similarly, while connecting to the "mysql" database, the hostname provided to the mysql command should also be the "internal ip address" of the host EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you! hopefully my hair will grow back now! I did what you advised and it worked instantly....been all day trying until I read your post.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing similar issue. Use only number part of the DNS name which is say for example the public DNS name is ec2-13-114-245-645.compute-1.amazonaws.com then use only 13.114.245.645 for connecting to that instance.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Login on to local mariadb/mysql server & give below command:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.0.1.40'  IDENTIFIED BY 'redhat' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Here,
 10.0.1.40 is my remote ec2 instance ip address.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i solved in my AWS ubuntu(18.04) Server. Here is the steps:

- Open 3306 port from security_group-> InBound rule.
- configure /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file : **bind-address=0.0.0.0** Using this it will allow all IP to connect with mySql remotely
- **Add privilege to user in mysql**:

  - **GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to YOUR_USER@'YOUR.PRIVATE_IP.ADDRESS.HERE' IDENTIFIED BY 'AN_USER_PASSWORD'**;

The final step is important. Here you are adding User, Private IP address with password which user will use to remote login.

**Example** :

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to root@'XX.XX.XX.XX' IDENTIFIED BY 'ADMIN_AWS123';

Here **root** is your user, **XX.XX.XX.XX** is your private IP address and **ADMIN_AWS123** is your remote password.

Hope this will help you :)