# Unable to connect to dockerized mysql db remotely

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, docker

On my `AWS ec2` server I have `docker 1.9.1` installed.
In an image `test_image` based from `ubuntu:trusty` official docker image, I have tried to setup the LEMP(Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP) architecture.

Following is the docker command i have used to start my container:

```
docker run --name test_1 -d -p 80:80 -p 3306:3306 test_image /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo daemonized docker container; sleep 5000; done"
```

I have exposed port `80` and `3306` to the host's network interface and have also allowed AWS's security group to allow inbound connections to these ports. Connection type in security group is: `MYSQL/Aurora` and protocol is: `TCP` (I know its not very secure, its only for initial implementation. Production setup will be different)

I followed this DigitalOcean tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

After installing Nginx and starting it I am able to test it in the browser via ec2's pubic ip i.e. http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx shows the default nginx welcome page.

While installing MySQL, I followed the following commands in the docker container:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
mysql_install_db
/etc/init.d/mysql start
mysql_secure_installation
```

I have given a password to my `root` user and during `mysql_secure_installation` i had allowed remote access to root user.

`mysql -u root -p` command from inside the container connects me to the mysql db but not from outside the container.

Also from my local machine:
I tried with mysql-client:
`mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u root -p`

I got the following error: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (111)`

and also through mysql workbench but I still can't connect to the mysql db.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your host mysql's my.cnf set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 so that mysql listens on all network interfaces

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

The default config is:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I still can't connect but the error message on my local machine in mysql-client changed to: `ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.` 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' is my local's public ip. And on the ec2 host its now: `ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'ip-zzz-zzz-zzz-zzz.ec2.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

Comment: You have to grant access to your machine: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'yourremotehost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';` This post is helpful too: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328150/1130-host-amazon-ec2-ip-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: But I am trying to access as the root user. Shouldn't I already have all the privileges?

Comment: The previous command allow user with a specific ip address `@remoteIP`. To allow root user for all remote ip `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. So basically even if the root user is trying to connect to the database from a remote host, he has to be explicitly granted privileges. Right?

Comment: Or rather the remote host is being provided privilege to connect using the root user.

Comment: You're right! It's not the default behaviour because of security concerns.